# "Sen rigardi": Which preposition+infinitive combos are possible?

Tags: prepositions, infinitive

I often encounter prepositional phrases such as ***sen rigardi***:

> Mi forlasis ŝin **sen rigardi** dorsen. *(From a story by J. Camacho.)*

Are other preposition+infinitive combinations possible? For example: **kun rigardi**, **per rigardi**, **je rigardi** and so on.

If not, why?

Comment: You might also be interested in this related question https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/921/alternativoj-por-rolvorteto-plus-i-verbo (Note, I’m not saying it’s a duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sen, por, anstataŭ —i* are all very common, and it is easy to invent examples for some other prepositions:

> *Vi faris al mi komplezon per peti lin telefoni.* You did me a favour by asking him to ring.
>
> *Ni diskutis pri aĉeti novan aŭton.* We discussed buying a new car.

However, Zamenhof did not like this form (excepting only *por* and *anstataŭ*). Many verbs are constructed by using a preposition as a prefix to another verb, e.g. *priparoli, kunhavi, alproksimiĝi*, and the presence or absence of a space is not audible in speech.

It isn't hard to rephrase those sentences:

> *Vi faris al mi komplezon petante lin telefoni.* You did me a favour asking him to ring.
>
> *Vi faris al mi komplezon kiam vi petis lin telefoni.* You did me a favour when you asked him to ring.
>
> *Vi faris al mi komplezon per via peto al li telefoni / ke li telefonu.* You did me a favour by your request to him that he ring.
>
> *Ni diskutis, ĉu aĉeti novan aŭton.* We discussed whether to buy a new car.
>
> *Ni diskutis, ĉu ni aĉetu novan aŭton.* We discussed whether we should buy a new car.

Here's Zamenhof's comment on *sen —i*:

> Kiel ni diras «mi vidis lin sana» (= «ke li estas sana») tiel laŭ mia opinio ni povas ankaŭ diri «mi vidis lin kuri» (= «ke li kuras»), «mi aŭdis lin paroli» (= «ke li parolas»); sed la esprimojn «li faris ĉion sen ridi» aŭ «li restis du tagojn sen manĝi» mi ne konsilus al vi uzi. **Prepozicion antaŭ verbo mi konsilus uzi nur en okazo de neceseco, se alie ni ne povas bone esprimi nian penson.** Sed anstataŭ «sen ridi» aŭ «sen manĝi» ni povas ja tre bone diri «sen rido», «sen manĝo» aŭ «neniom ridante», «nenion manĝante». *Respondo 20, La Revuo, 1907, Junio*

See also *Respondo 37*, which is even more emphatic. In practice I think that people just find it easier to say *sen rigardi* than *ne rigardante*, or at least find that it flows more naturally.

---

I noticed your question about *Dankon pro veni*. The problem with that sentence is that *veni* is floating unattached to a subject, but is not meant absolutely; and for that reason, in my personal opinion, *Dankon por veni* is better phrased as *Dankon por via veno.* The specific form *por —i* is almost always used to express the purpose of the action of the main verb, and is therefore attached to the subject of the main verb: e.g. after the sentence *Mi telefonos lin por kontroli* we may ask *Kiu kontrolos? Mi kontrolos.* But in *Mi dankas vin por veni* the word *veni* is confusingly attached to *vin*, not *mi*. Compare with, say, *Mi telefonis kaj varme dankis ŝin por fliki nian rilaton iomete.* ("I telephoned and warmly thanked her in order to patch up our relations a bit.")

As to *por/pro*, they are both correct, although I think *pro* is more common; the expression *danki por* is legitimate (and Zamenhofian) because it suggests an exchange: *Li pagis por mia abono, kaj mi dankis lin por lia pago.*

Answer (score 3):

They're all *possible* but some are more common than others. Common prepositions used with infinitives are *por, sen,* and *anstataŭ*. I've always just ascribed this to tradition.

If you want to use a preposition with an infinitive, you can often use *ol* (antaŭ ol paroli) or a different preposition. (*Dankon **pro** via venado / dankon **por** veni*).

Some cases are considered less than ideal by some, but they're well established. My advice is to avoid the patterns that are not well established. (e.g. *Miaj esperoj pri lasi tiun-ĉi insulon* is probably questionable.) You'll find stray examples with *antaŭ* followed by a preposition. Generally it's better with "ol".

Comment: Would it be wrong to say *Dankon **pro** veni*? Or is it just untraditional?

Comment: What's the difference between wrong and untraditional? Language is defined by how it's used, is it not? I would never say "dankon pro veni" and I would consider it wrong *because* it is non-traditional.

Comment: I have been corrected for using "por" and told that "pro" is always the preposition to use after "Dankon"

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro - without more context, I would say that the people who corrected you and told you that "pro" is "always the preposition" - are simply wrong. A simple search in Tekstaro shows that "dankon por" is less common that "dankon pro" - but it's also *zamenhofa.* A simple search doesn't show the whole picture, however, because they mean different things and are used in different ways. A more sophisticated search (e.g.  \bdank\FI .{0,25}\bp\w\w\b) shows numerous examples of "dank-" with "por" - and in other ways.

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro- It looks like this is already a question in our database - https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/187/dankon-por-via-respondo-or-dankon-pro-via-respondo

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Thank you for the link! Great