# sen followed by a clause

Tags: word-usage

I found in this post

["Sen rigardi": Which preposition+infinitive combos are possible?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3407/sen-rigardi-which-prepositioninfinitive-combos-are-possible)

that the form *sen* + infinitive is possible, but it seems that it is not recommended by Zamenhof. Is that form more common nowadays?

I have not found any examples for *sen* followed by a clause. Just as *antaŭ ol* is to *antaŭ* + infinitive, what is the corresponding form for *sen* + infinitive? And for *anstataŭ* + infinitive? Conversely, what would be the form followed by infinitive for *post kiam*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the corresponding form for sen + infinitive?

*Tekstaro* yields *sen ke ĝi ricevu ian privilegion<sup>Z</sup>* and  many more later examples. While *sen + -i* raises some eyebrows (not mine), *sen ke + -u/as/is/os/us* is generally accepted. It is often used with *-u*.

> And for anstataŭ + infinitive?

Again from *Tekstaro*, *anstataŭ ke ĉiu lernas diversajn lingvojn<sup>Z</sup>,* from *Esenco kaj Estonteco de la Ideo de Lingvo Internacia.* You get a hit from *Vojaĝo al Kazohinio* too. However, *anstataŭ ke* does not seem to be widely used. Surprisingly, you get three *Tekstaro* hits (none of them from Z) for *anstataŭ ol + -i,* which I would never use (I’m for *anstataŭ + -i,* without *ol*)

> Conversely, what would be the form followed by infinitive for post kiam?

In *Artikoloj el Monato* you find *post produkti elektron per vaporturbinoj,* and in *La Ondo de Esperanto:* *post celebri ĉe UK dujaran enkondukan periodon,* so *post + -i* is used in modern newsmagazines. I would prefer *post produktado de elektro,*  *post celebro ĉe UK,* and so on. It is worth noting that in *Tekstaro* you get some hits (all from Russia) for *post ol* instead of *post kiam,* which is something I sometimes find myself saying.

To resume:

- *sen* + infinitive is debated, *sen ke* + clause is OK.
- *anstataŭ (ol?)* + infintive is OK, *anstataŭ ke* + clause is OK but rare.
- *antaŭ (ol)* + infinitive is probably OK, *antaŭ ol* + clause is OK.
- *post* + infinitive is maybe OK, *post kiam/(ol?)* + clause is OK.

*-inte* and *-onte* are good alternatives for *post/antaŭ + -i,* as *post/antaŭ + -ado* often are.

Answer (score 3):

Preposition plus infinitive is copied from numerous national languages but (with the exception of `por/anstataŭ`) grammatically incorrect. Some alternatives:

- sen - ne rigardante, sen rigardo, sen kurado
- post - rigardinte
- antaŭ - rigardonte, antaŭ ol rigardi, antaŭ rigardo, antaŭ la skribado

Especially the *-ado* form seems adequate.

Whether nowadays such grammar rules are more relaxed is hard to tell. One hears *sen*-forms ("sen scii") sufficient often, and it just might have become time to accept preposition + infinitive. For now let's keep to official grammatics.

---

I found in [**Reta-Vortaro**](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) an opposite stand point:

> **Rim.:** Kvankam la uzado de **sen** antaŭ infinitivo estas neofta, ĝi estas tute korekta, ĉar logika kaj utila. La kutima dirmaniero **ne
>   ...-ante** ne estas ĝuste samsenca, ĉar ĝi ne esprimas la neatenditecon
>   aŭ la esceptecon de la foresto. Ekz.: *ne parolante* (ĉar mia temo ne
>   estas) *pri la versarto, mi do ne analizos la ritmon; sen paroli* (eĉ se
>   oni ne volas paroli) *pri la versarto, la tie esprimita ideo estas
>   admirinda.*

Comment: I found 9 hits in Tekstaro for "sen diri". Why is this grammatically incorrect? PMEG doesn't deprecate this usage, and it gives the example sentence "Ŝi foriris sen diri eĉ unu vorton.". I even noticed that PMEG sometimes puts an infinitive after "sed" in the text explaining Esperanto grammar.

Comment: I have found similar in ReVo, see extended answer. Though I learned to avoid _sen_, and indeed considering the rigid grammatical categories in E-o I still cannot be convinced otherwise. There is a small essay, booklet on this topic.